# libavg 64-bit on Windows

Tags: python, 64-bit, libavg

I want to use libavg for a Python UI but they sadly don't have 64 bit binaries for Windows. I always install the 64 bit python 2.7 package but would that be considered the default? I'd had to write an app using libavg and then have a lot of people not be able to use it because it's not 64 bit.

Or does anyone know if there are precompiled 64 bit libavg binaries available? I'm not keen on compiling it myself...